# is there any way I could make this code shorter?

Tags: java, if-statement, netbeans, java.util.scanner

This is a simple code, however, I wanna know if I could somehow make it shorter, I don't know that much to even know what to look for, so I'm not looking for someone to rewrite if for me, I only want someone to tell me what methods should I use, how do I call a variable the user wrote outside `if`, or such things that would help me. I'm new to coding, so sorry if I'm making a stupid question.

```
    System.out.println("Write name: ");
    name = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Write last name: ");
    lastName = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Write id: ");
    id = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Write your average GPA: ");
    average = s.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Your name is:" +name+ "\nYour last name is: " 
   +lastName+ "\nYour GPA is: " +average+ "\nYearly tuition is: " 
   +tuitionCost);

    if(average >= 9.0){
        System.out.println("Your discount is: 20% off.");
        d = 100-20;
        total = (d * tuitionCost)/100;
        System.out.println("Your yearly tuition is: " +total);
    }
    else if(average <= 8.99 && average >= 8.5){
        System.out.println("Your discount is: 10% off.");
        d = 100-10;
        total = (d * tuitionCost)/100;
        System.out.println("Your yearly tuition is: " +total);
    }
    else if(average <= 8.49 && average >= 8.0){
        System.out.println("Your discount is: 5% off.");
        d = 100-5;
        total = (d * tuitionCost)/100;
        System.out.println("Your yearly tuition is: " +total);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("You have no discount. Your yearly tuition is: " 
   +tuitionCost);
    }
```

Comment: You can use switch statements in place of if-else statements as well and create a method that calculates your total= (d*tuitioncost)/100. And then you can call this method.

Comment: And you should get rid of all the "<=" comparisons, as you leave blind spots like "8.995" which would fall into the last "else" block. Yes, this usually should not happen, but you never know, especially if the discount is calculated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn your discounts into a class:

```
class Discount {
    private final List<Tier> tiers = List.of(
        new Tier(0.0, 0), new Tier(8.0, 5), new Tier(8.5, 10), new Tier(9.0, 20));

    private class Tier {
        private final double gpa;
        private final int discount;
    }

    private int discount(double gpa) {
        return tiers.stream().filter(t -> t.gpa <= gpa)
            .mapToDouble(t -> t.discount).max().getAsDouble();
    }

    public double tuition(double gpa, double base) {
        return (1.0 - discount(gpa)/100.0) * base;
    }

    public String discountMessage(double gpa) {
        if (discount(gpa) == 0)
            return "You have no discount";
        else
            return "Your discount is " + discount(gpa) + "%";
    }
}
```

I've left some details out but you get the idea.

This may be overkill - it would depend on how often the tiers might change. But it does satisfy the DRY principle (don't repeat yourself). This makes your code more resilient: it's less likely you will change your code in one place and forget to change it elsewhere.

You mention making your code shorter. I subscribe to the principle that you should look for clarity before brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the logic certainly could be *simplified* a little:  if you are careful to write the `if..else if` sequence in descending order, your logic could simply be:

```
 /* CAUTION: KEEP IN DESCENDING ORDER!  ... yes, add this comment! */
 if (average >= 9.0) {
 }
 else if (average >= 8.5) {
 }
```

... and so on.  *(Which also makes each of the `if`-conditions consistent.)*

Now, be very careful that your `else` case does all of the things that all of the other cases do: it should assign values to `d` and to `total`.  It should "look exactly like all the other ones."

Beyond that, I probably wouldn't change a single thing, and here's why:  the logic is now "fairly obvious at first glance," *and* each of the cases are clearly independent.  If "the marketing department" suddenly comes up with a grand new idea which only applies to some of the cases but not others ... *(and marketing departments always do)* ... you're covered.  Future programmers could simply "make small, targeted commits" to this logic and they'd never have to re-write it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could simplify by

```
int discount = -1;
if(average >= 9.0){
    discount = 20;
}
else if(average <= 8.99 && average >= 8.5){
    discount = 10;
}
.
.

 System.out.printf("Your discount is: %d%% off.%n", discount);
 d = 100-discount;
 total = (d * tuitionCost)/100;
 System.out.println("Your yearly tuition is: " +total);
```

**Note**

The `if-else` could be better as a swtich

Comment: I liked this method, it was what I was looking for, but it's showing me errors, such as `Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '% o'`